# Transformer using Network data

Tags: transformer-model, huggingface

I have a dataset and would like to train it with this one transformer. The dataset consists of 1500 columns (numbers between 0 and 1) and one label column. At the end I want to give a dataset to the model and have the prediction as label. I have already found out that byt5 is suitable for this but how can I use it exactly?